Animate "aspect-ratio" with GSAP
I'm trying to animate a div from "full-screen" to a "16/9" ratio with some margins.
The results before and after the animation is what I intend to have, except the animation of the height.
Any idea how to go full-screen to 16/9 without any bump?
https://jsfiddle.net/LaitEau/kyvt103o/1/
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const coverVideo = document.querySelector('.cover-video-full');

  gsap.from(coverVideo, {
    duration: 3.6, // Durée de l'animation en secondes
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
    top: '-16px',
    left:'-16px',
    opacity: 0.2,
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    ease: "power2.inOut" // Effet d'animation
  });
});

.cover-video-full {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  aspect-ratio: none;
  top:-16px;
  left:-16px;
  opacity:0.5;
  position: relative;
  background:blue;
}

